# Localhost Development with Server has a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key error

Tags: java, google-chrome, tomcat, https, certificate

Since two days I get this error when connecting via HTTPS to my local application running on `localhost`:

Server has a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key

I use latest Mac OSX and latest Google Chrome. My application runs on a Tomcat. How can I create a new self-signed certificate that will be accepted by Google? I just want to continue to develop! So any hack is welcome.